# How to understand 'quae prosum sola nocendo'?

Tags: grammar-identification, latin-to-english-translation, ovidius, metamorphoses, gerundive

There is a line in Ovid's *Metamorphoses* II 519, which I don't understand at all

(Juno's complaint)

> 'quaeritis, aetheriis quare regina deorum
>   sedibus huc adsim? pro me tenet altera caelum!
>   mentior, obscurum nisi nox cum fecerit orbem,
>   nuper honoratas summo, mea vulnera, caelo
>   videritis stellas illic, ubi circulus axem
>   ultimus extremum spatioque brevissimus ambit.
>   et vero quisquam Iunonem laedere nolit
>   offensamque tremat, **quae prosum sola nocendo**?
>   o ego quantum egi! quam vasta potentia nostra est!<

*Nocendo* is gerundive from *noceo* — "to do harm, inflict injury, hurt" — and *prosum* is a verb "to be useful, be of use, do good, benefit, profit, serve".

This line is translated as 'who do but help where I would harm?' (F. J. Miller)

The gerundive (passive adjective) would be then 'to be harmful towards something, (requiring, needing, must be harmed) and should usually have the agent in the dative — here perhaps *sola*?

And *quae* can be f.nom., f.Pl.nom., or n.Pl. nom., acc. — what or who (as it cannot be Iuppiter?) does it refer to, I do not know.

I assume *prosum* means then that she is saying 'I do good'…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Nocendo* is a gerund (noun) here, not a gerundive (adjective). Therefore, it's active in meaning. It's ablative to show the means by which Juno does good. *Quae* is f. nom. sing. and refers to *Iunonem*, who is the 'I' of the relative clause.

> ...I who alone do good by doing harm

(Note that *sola* couldn't be the object of *nocendo* (or the agent, because *nocendo*, as a gerund, isn't passive in meaning), because it's not dative; the form would have to be *soli*. In this case, *nocendo* is being used 'absolutely' – that is, without an object; she's talking about doing harm in general.)

Comment: Good analysis. It might help to explain the meaning of this line, which is a paradox: why or how does Juno help people by harming them? The answer is that she tried to harm the nymph Callisto by turning her into a bear, but in turned out her attempt only helped Callisto in the end (because it made Jupiter turn Callisto into a heavenly bear when the nymph's son was about to slay her). That's why Juno is complaining about her powerlessness here.